# Turning text content into object

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating an API in js serving IntelliSense service with Monaco.

Issue is when I am having a dependency served by Monaco editor:

```
define(
    [ "text!path/api.js", "text!path/swiper", "Api", "vs/editor/editor.main"],
    function (apiText, swiper, Api, e) {
```

and now first dep *text!path/api.js* returns string as:

```
"///<summary>
/// Swiper method
/// </summary>
/// <param name="el" type="string">element</param>
Api.prototype.swiper = function (el) {
    $.platform.swiper(el);
    log('spinnwe() method called');
};"
```

Now I'd like to turn it's content into an object, but **JSON.parse(apiText);** returns issue (comments are not recognisable by js):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (codeEditor.js:33), <anonymous>:1:6)
    at codeEditor.js:33
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1597)
    at Module.check (require.js:845)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1083)
    at require.js:130
    at require.js:1126
    at each (require.js:58)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1125)
```

Is there any chance getting an object?